# rewrite function order_pay in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Users who are not logged in do not have access to the following page :

http://localhost/wordpress/checkout/order-pay/5962/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_Cx9yQiL8wTX0H

Users who are not logged in should not access the following page :

http://localhost/wordpress/checkout/order-pay/5962/?key=wc_order_Cx9yQiL8wTX0H

path : C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php

```
/**
 * Show the pay page.
 *
 * @throws Exception When validate fails.
 * @param int $order_id Order ID.
 */
private static function order_pay( $order_id ) {

    do_action( 'before_woocommerce_pay' );

    $order_id = absint( $order_id );

    // Pay for existing order.
    if ( isset( $_GET['pay_for_order'], $_GET['key'] ) && $order_id ) { // WPCS: input var ok, CSRF ok.
        try {
            $order_key = isset( $_GET['key'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_GET['key'] ) ) : ''; // WPCS: input var ok, CSRF ok.
            $order     = wc_get_order( $order_id );

            // Order or payment link is invalid.
            if ( ! $order || $order->get_id() !== $order_id || ! hash_equals( $order->get_order_key(), $order_key ) ) {
                throw new Exception( __( 'Sorry, this order is invalid and cannot be paid for.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }

            // Logged out customer does not have permission to pay for this order.
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'pay_for_order', $order_id ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
                echo '<div class="woocommerce-info">' . esc_html__( 'Please log in to your account below to continue to the payment form.', 'woocommerce' ) . '</div>';
                woocommerce_login_form(
                    array(
                        'redirect' => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                    )
                );
                return;
            }

            // Add notice if logged in customer is trying to pay for guest order.
            if ( ! $order->get_user_id() && is_user_logged_in() ) {
                // If order has does not have same billing email then current logged in user then show warning.
                if ( $order->get_billing_email() !== wp_get_current_user()->user_email ) {
                    wc_print_notice( __( 'You are paying for a guest order. Please continue with payment only if you recognize this order.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
                }
            }

            // Logged in customer trying to pay for someone else's order.
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'pay_for_order', $order_id ) ) {
                throw new Exception( __( 'This order cannot be paid for. Please contact us if you need assistance.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }

            // Does not need payment.
            if ( ! $order->needs_payment() ) {
                /* translators: %s: order status */
                throw new Exception( sprintf( __( 'This order&rsquo;s status is &ldquo;%s&rdquo;&mdash;it cannot be paid for. Please contact us if you need assistance.', 'woocommerce' ), wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ) );
            }

            // Ensure order items are still stocked if paying for a failed order. Pending orders do not need this check because stock is held.
            if ( ! $order->has_status( wc_get_is_pending_statuses() ) ) {
                $quantities = array();

                foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
                    if ( $item && is_callable( array( $item, 'get_product' ) ) ) {
                        $product = $item->get_product();

                        if ( ! $product ) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        $quantities[ $product->get_stock_managed_by_id() ] = isset( $quantities[ $product->get_stock_managed_by_id() ] ) ? $quantities[ $product->get_stock_managed_by_id() ] + $item->get_quantity() : $item->get_quantity();
                    }
                }

                foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
                    if ( $item && is_callable( array( $item, 'get_product' ) ) ) {
                        $product = $item->get_product();

                        if ( ! $product ) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pay_order_product_in_stock', $product->is_in_stock(), $product, $order ) ) {
                            /* translators: %s: product name */
                            throw new Exception( sprintf( __( 'Sorry, "%s" is no longer in stock so this order cannot be paid for. We apologize for any inconvenience caused.', 'woocommerce' ), $product->get_name() ) );
                        }

                        // We only need to check products managing stock, with a limited stock qty.
                        if ( ! $product->managing_stock() || $product->backorders_allowed() ) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        // Check stock based on all items in the cart and consider any held stock within pending orders.
                        $held_stock     = wc_get_held_stock_quantity( $product, $order->get_id() );
                        $required_stock = $quantities[ $product->get_stock_managed_by_id() ];

                        if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pay_order_product_has_enough_stock', ( $product->get_stock_quantity() >= ( $held_stock + $required_stock ) ), $product, $order ) ) {
                            /* translators: 1: product name 2: quantity in stock */
                            throw new Exception( sprintf( __( 'Sorry, we do not have enough "%1$s" in stock to fulfill your order (%2$s available). We apologize for any inconvenience caused.', 'woocommerce' ), $product->get_name(), wc_format_stock_quantity_for_display( $product->get_stock_quantity() - $held_stock, $product ) ) );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            WC()->customer->set_props(
                array(
                    'billing_country'  => $order->get_billing_country() ? $order->get_billing_country() : null,
                    'billing_state'    => $order->get_billing_state() ? $order->get_billing_state() : null,
                    'billing_postcode' => $order->get_billing_postcode() ? $order->get_billing_postcode() : null,
                )
            );
            WC()->customer->save();

            $available_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();

            if ( count( $available_gateways ) ) {
                current( $available_gateways )->set_current();
            }

            /**
             * Allows the text of the submit button on the Pay for Order page to be changed.
             *
             * @param string $text The text of the button.
             *
             * @since 3.0.2
             */
            $order_button_text = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pay_order_button_text', __( 'Pay for order', 'woocommerce' ) );

            /**
             * Triggered right before the Pay for Order form, after validation of the order and customer.
             *
             * @param WC_Order $order              The order that is being paid for.
             * @param string   $order_button_text  The text for the submit button.
             * @param array    $available_gateways All available gateways.
             *
             * @since 6.6
             */
            do_action( 'before_woocommerce_pay_form', $order, $order_button_text, $available_gateways );

            wc_get_template(
                'checkout/form-pay.php',
                array(
                    'order'              => $order,
                    'available_gateways' => $available_gateways,
                    'order_button_text'  => $order_button_text,
                )
            );

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            wc_print_notice( $e->getMessage(), 'error' );
        }
    } elseif ( $order_id ) {

        // Pay for order after checkout step.
        $order_key = isset( $_GET['key'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_GET['key'] ) ) : ''; // WPCS: input var ok, CSRF ok.
        $order     = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        if ( $order && $order->get_id() === $order_id && hash_equals( $order->get_order_key(), $order_key ) ) {

            if ( $order->needs_payment() ) {

                wc_get_template( 'checkout/order-receipt.php', array( 'order' => $order ) );

            } else {
                /* translators: %s: order status */
                wc_print_notice( sprintf( __( 'This order&rsquo;s status is &ldquo;%s&rdquo;&mdash;it cannot be paid for. Please contact us if you need assistance.', 'woocommerce' ), wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ), 'error' );
            }
        } else {
            wc_print_notice( __( 'Sorry, this order is invalid and cannot be paid for.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        }
    } else {
        wc_print_notice( __( 'Invalid order.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }

    do_action( 'after_woocommerce_pay' );
}
```

**How to rewrite the above function and put my condition in it**

I know that the file of this page is at the following address :

C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/order-receipt.php

But I want to display the following 2 conditions when the user enters :

```
        if ( $order && $order->get_id() === $order_id && hash_equals( $order->get_order_key(), $order_key ) ) {

            if ( $order->needs_payment() ) {

                wc_get_template( 'checkout/order-receipt.php', array( 'order' => $order ) );

            } else {
                /* translators: %s: order status */
                wc_print_notice( sprintf( __( 'This order&rsquo;s status is &ldquo;%s&rdquo;&mdash;it cannot be paid for. Please contact us if you need assistance.', 'woocommerce' ), wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ), 'error' );
            }
        } else {
            wc_print_notice( __( 'Sorry, this order is invalid and cannot be paid for.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        }
```

**How to rewrite the above function and put my condition in it**

Comment: You should never change the coding of core files, or anything provided by a 3rd-party plugin - your changes will get lost on the next update. If anything, you should do this via the hook system. This method executes all functions added to `before_woocommerce_pay` first, so handle it in there. Although you will probably not be able to stop the rest of the processing, if you just show output from some templates in there - ideally, you should probably redirect to a new page that shows whatever information you need to present, and `exit` after you made that redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the path to your original file that you want to edit : /plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php

You must create the same path in your child template : /themes/theme-child/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php

Then put the following code in the function file in your child template :
/themes/theme-child/function.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php';
```

Now you can make any desired changes in this file